# Какой использовать контрол для хелпа?

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме необходимо разместить небольшой хелп с описанием параметров и примерами. Какой есть контрол, чтобы я мог поместить описание параметров в гриде, примеры использования параметров в другом контроле, но чтобы мог прокручивать сие в форме? Типа как в браузере прокрутка по странице.

Comment: я бы использовал браузерный движок, тот же хромиум например, для унификации доступа к документации с сайта поддержки продукта и прямо из приложения. А так хоть тоже грид и используйте с соответствующими настройками отображения данных, или кастомные контролы с произвольной разметкой собранные в какой-нибудь flowlayoutpanel или даже просто panel с автоскролом. Много вариантов, даже без учета коммерческих решений. MS так вообще отправляют сразу на нужную страницу MSDN через дефолтный браузер системы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте оформить хелп в виде одного из контрола (или комбинации контролов):

1. RichTextBox
2. LinkLabel (возможностей мало)
3. WebBrowser (с открытием локального файла)

Как вариант можно сделать ссылку на форме (что то вроде 'см. подробнее'). При нажатии на нее открывать локальный файл со справкой (html, pdf, chm и т.д.).

подробнее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311/formatting-text-in-winform-label), [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194851/load-local-html-file-in-a-c-sharp-webbrowser) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220134/displaying-a-pdf-file-from-winform)